# How can I fire event on click?

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

I am expecting that by click on "project" the alert "clicked" is fired. But nothing happens

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".main-table").clone(true).appendTo('#table-scroll').addClass('clone');
});


$('.table-wrap').scrollLeft($('[data-date="2018-04-01"]').offset().left - 82);



$( ".project" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

```css
.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-scroll table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table-scroll th,
.table-scroll td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.clone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.clone th,
.clone td {
  visibility: hidden
}

.clone td,
.clone th {
  border-color: transparent
}

.clone tbody th {
  visibility: visible;
}

.clone .fixed-side {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: none;
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.clone thead,
.clone tfoot {
  background: transparent;
}

.gantt-h {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #b0b0b0;
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.last {
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.gantt td {
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.today{
background-color:pink;
width:100px;
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <table class="main-table table gantt">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" scope="col" class="left-h" style="border-bottom:2px solid #f4f4f4;color:#b0b0b0">Task</th>

          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h" style="font-weight:normal;color:#b0b0b0;">30 Mar</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">31 Mar</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">01 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">02 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">03 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">04 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">05 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">06 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">07 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">08 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">09 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">10 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">11 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">12 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">13 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">14 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">15 Apr</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side project"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> Projekt 1</th>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> blue</th>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-03-30"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-03-31"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-08"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> green</th>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> yellow</th>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> pink</th>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> orange</th>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It does alert. The issue is that the `th` is not in the initial viewport because the row is scrolled.

Comment: Actually, the click event is fired correctly.

Comment: @Hikarunomemory I click on "Projekt 1" and nothing happens

Comment: @dork I do not get an alert

Comment: cause it auto scroll left from this : `$('.table-wrap').scrollLeft($('[data-date="2018-04-01"]').offset().left - 82);`

Comment: @Hikarunomemory Yes I need the autoscroll. But at the sametime I want to be able to click on the projekt names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is just a workaround**. The main idea is to calculate the coordinate you clicked and check if in `th`'s range.

NOTE: You can find which `th` you clicked base on this code.

Edit: Now only triggers when click on the first `th` in `tbody`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".main-table").clone(true).appendTo('#table-scroll').addClass('clone');
});


$('.table-wrap').scrollLeft($('[data-date="2018-04-01"]').offset().left - 82);



// $( ".project" ).on( "click", function() {
//   alert("clicked");
// });

$("body").on("click", function(e) {
  // the coordinate you clicked
  var x = e.clientX
  var y = e.clientY
  
  // all th.fixed-side in cloned table (include thead and tbody)
  var fixedSide = $('table.clone th.fixed-side')

  // calculate the height of cloned table's tbody
  // var tableHeight = fixedSide.get(0).offsetHeight * fixedSide.length - 1;

  // only first th in tbody
  var tableHeight = fixedSide.get(0).offsetHeight;

  // th's width
  var offsetWidth = fixedSide.get(0).offsetWidth;

  // calculate offsetTop and offsetLeft from body
  var offset = getOffset(fixedSide.get(0))
  
  // skip thead's th
  offset.Top += fixedSide.get(0).offsetHeight;

  // check if click inside the range
  var inRange = (x >= offset.Left && x <= offset.Left + offsetWidth) &&
    (y >= offset.Top && y <= offset.Top + tableHeight)

  if (inRange) {
    alert("clicked");
  }
});

function getOffset(element) {
  var offsetTop = 0;
  var offsetLeft = 0;
  do {
    offsetTop += element.offsetTop;
    offsetLeft += element.offsetLeft;
  } while (element = element.offsetParent);
  var offset = {
    Left: offsetLeft,
    Top: offsetTop,
  }
  return offset;
}
```

```css
.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-scroll table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table-scroll th,
.table-scroll td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.clone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.clone th,
.clone td {
  visibility: hidden
}

.clone td,
.clone th {
  border-color: transparent
}

.clone tbody th {
  visibility: visible;
}

.clone .fixed-side {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: none;
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.clone thead,
.clone tfoot {
  background: transparent;
}

.gantt-h {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #b0b0b0;
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.last {
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.gantt td {
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.today {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <table class="main-table table gantt">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" scope="col" class="left-h" style="border-bottom:2px solid #f4f4f4;color:#b0b0b0">Task</th>

          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h" style="font-weight:normal;color:#b0b0b0;">30 Mar</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">31 Mar</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">01 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">02 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">03 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">04 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">05 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">06 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">07 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">08 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">09 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">10 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">11 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">12 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">13 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">14 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">15 Apr</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side project"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> Projekt 1</th>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> blue</th>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-03-30"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-03-31"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-08"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> green</th>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> yellow</th>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> pink</th>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> orange</th>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh I just realized something. When I click on blue or green, the alert box appears also. But it should only appear by click on "Projekt 1"

Comment: I tried to solve it by changing this line:  `var fixedSide = $('table.clone th.project')` but it is not working

Comment: I edited the post. Now only triggers when click on the first `th` in `tbody`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your CSS. You do not need to use `table-wrap` class. Remove that CSS and it will work:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".main-table").clone(true).appendTo('#table-scroll').addClass('clone');
});


$('.table-wrap').scrollLeft($('[data-date="2018-04-01"]').offset().left - 82);



$( ".project" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

```css
.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table-scroll table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table-scroll th,
.table-scroll td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.clone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.clone th,
.clone td {
  visibility: hidden
}

.clone td,
.clone th {
  border-color: transparent
}

.clone tbody th {
  visibility: visible;
}

.clone .fixed-side {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: none;
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.clone thead,
.clone tfoot {
  background: transparent;
}

.gantt-h {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #b0b0b0;
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.last {
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.gantt td {
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.today{
background-color:pink;
width:100px;
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <table class="main-table table gantt">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" scope="col" class="left-h" style="border-bottom:2px solid #f4f4f4;color:#b0b0b0">Task</th>

          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h" style="font-weight:normal;color:#b0b0b0;">30 Mar</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">31 Mar</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">01 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">02 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">03 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">04 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">05 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">06 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">07 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">08 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">09 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">10 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">11 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">12 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">13 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">14 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">15 Apr</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side project"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> Projekt 1</th>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> blue</th>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-03-30"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-03-31"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-08"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> green</th>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> yellow</th>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> pink</th>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> orange</th>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But then my vertical scroll feature is gone

Answer (score 0):

Try to write project class click event in document.ready like below code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $( ".project" ).on( "click", function() {
      alert("clicked");
   });
});
```